# OSX find with regex for a standard file ending

Tags: macos, regex

I'm trying to find all files with a pretty standard file format (all duplicate media types automatically created by Wordpress). Using [Regexr](https://regexr.com/), I was able to put something together fairly quickly. However, OSX find regex doesn't mix well with regexr (which uses javascript by default, but can uses PHP pattern matching).

I'm wondering how I can adapt this to Mac OSX BSD style regex matching. I've been hacking away at this for a while now I'd love some expert direction. Specifically, I'm having trouble with number ranges, ie allowing between 1 and 4 digits separated by an x.

I can make this work with the following egrep, but not find:

```
ls | egrep "\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}\.(png|gif|jpg)$"
```

The file formats I'm trying to find:

```
location-948510_1280-1024x1024.png
location-948510_1280-10x10.png
location-948510_1280-50x300.png
location-948510_1280-4x29.png
```

The one that needs to be left out (as an example):

```
location-948510_1280.png
```

The find regex I'm trying to use:

```
find -E . -regex '.*\-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}\.(png|gif|jpg)$'
```

Example matching of pattern on regexr:

[image: regex on regexr]

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out while I was working through writing the question (I [rubber ducked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) myself apparently)

This ended up doing the job perfectly:

```
find -E . -regex '.*\-[0-9]{1,4}\x[0-9]{1,4}\.(png|gif|jpg)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\D` that means, "not a digit", before the wanted digits:

```
find -E . -regex '.*\D\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}\.(png|gif|jpg)$'
//           here __^^
```

Comment: This doesn't work, even if modified to have \D in front of both \d's: find -E . -regex '.*\D\d{1,4}x\D\d{1,4}\.(png|gif|jpg)$'

Comment: @hisnameisjimmy: ay be `\D` is not recognize, but that's strange because it is a standard, try with its signification: `[^0-9]`

Comment: No worries, I already figured it out (see my answer above).